# generate matrix with independent columns

Tags: python, numpy, python-hypothesis

I am trying to generate matrices with independent columns. At the moment I am using `assume` which works, but requires a lot of computation:

```
import sys
import hypothesis.strategies as st
import numpy as np
from hypothesis import assume
from hypothesis.extra.numpy import arrays

@st.composite
def data(draw, shape):
    elements = st.floats(min_value=-10, max_value=10)
    X = draw(arrays(np.float, shape, elements=elements))
    # independence check
    assume(np.linalg.cond(np.dot(X.T, X)) < 1 / sys.float_info.epsilon)
    return X
```

Is there a better way to directly create a matrix `X` with independent columns?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a partial solution that, instead of doing essentially rejection sampling, uses the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to generate your columns. It's partial, because it actually seems to be a bit slower than the rejection sampling approach (unless I did the timing wrong, somehow - I simply replaced `data` with your implementation), and I had to bake in a few assumptions for demonstration's sake (a bunch of them could be removed, of course). I still think the idea might be viable if optimized by a wiser wizard than me, so I'm putting it out here.

```py
import sys
import hypothesis.strategies as st
import numpy as np
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis.extra.numpy import arrays


def project_onto_u(u, v):
    return np.dot(u, v) / np.dot(u, u) * u


@st.composite
def data(draw, shape):
    elements = st.floats(
        min_value=0.01,
        max_value=10,
        allow_nan=False,
        allow_infinity=False,
        allow_subnormal=False,
    )
    V = draw(arrays(float, shape, elements=elements, unique=True))
    vectors = []
    for v in V:
        u = v - sum(project_onto_u(u_i, v) for u_i in vectors)
        vectors.append(u)
    X = np.vstack(vectors)
    assert X.shape == shape
    return X


@given(X=data(shape=(10, 10)))
def test_matrix_has_independent_columns(X):
    assert np.linalg.cond(np.dot(X.T, X)) < 1 / sys.float_info.epsilon
```